# Add element which behave as DIV after export to html in jasper report

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I want to add a element in Jasper Report(.jrxml file) which becomes DIV after export in html.

For that same element I also want to add id attribute for further manipulation after exporting it to HTML file.

So, basically I want final output should be like

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Is there any way to do that in jasper report.

Answer (score 0):

Add property line in jasper report

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.id" value="container"/>
```

and add staticText from jasper elements

```
<pageHeader>
<band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
    <staticText>
       <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="730" height="20">
           <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.id" value="container"/>
       </reportElement>

        <text><![CDATA[Test ]]></text>
    </staticText>
</band>
```